# Raspberry PI Zero with USB/Ethernet dongle

Tags: networking, ethernet, zero, dhcp

I have looked and looked and looked, I can't find an answer to this problem anywhere!

I want to connect my PI zero to an ethernet cable. I have a USB/Ethernet dongle. I have 3 zero's, all have USB-HUB hats. I plug in the dongle and reboot (which is what **every** video I've found says is all you have to do). When it comes back up, the ethernet port is recognized, but won't get an IP address.

Here's what ifconfig says:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0e:c6:78:62:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
```

The only hint I can find suggests I need to add this to the interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet DHCP
```

But this changes nothing. It seems that the DHCP client is not running (although it works for the WiFi). But when I google 'DHCP setup raspberry pi zero' all I get it how to setup a server.

Answer (score 1):

VERY Embarrassing!

The ethernet cable was not plugged in ‍♂️